# Exportar a excel desde mysql con php y mantener ceros a la izquierda

Tags: php, mysql, excel

tengo el resultado de una consulta `mysql` que contiene números con ceros a la izquierda, los cuales debo de mantener en la exportación a Excel. ejemplo: en BD aparece el numero `000018` al exportar a excel en la celda aparece `18`

Esta es la función que utilizo para exportar.

```html
<?php
require_once('conexion_db.php');
$slq = "select * from " . TABLE_EXPORT_PATRIMONIO . " ep, " . TABLE_EXPORT_COMPARATIVA_PATRI . " ex where ex.clave_patri = ep.entrega01_clave and ep.entrega01_envases <> '' and ep.entrega01_envases <> '0' and ep.entrega01_indicaciones = '' and ex.codigo_op <> ''";
$stmt = mysqli_query($conn, $slq);
$data = [];
$i = 1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt)){
    $data[$i]['id'] = $i;
    $data[$i]['codigo_op'] = $row['codigo_op'];
    $data[$i]['entrega01_clave'] = $row['entrega01_clave'];
    $data[$i]['descripcion_articulo'] = $row['descripcion_articulo'];
 $data[$i]['entrega01_envases'] = $row['entrega01_envases'];
 $data[$i]['entrega01_precio_unidad'] = $row['entrega01_precio_unidad'];
    $i++;
}
require_once('export_patrimonio_mysql_excel.php');
$export = new Export();

if(isset($_GET['export']) && $_GET['export'] == 'excel'){
    $export->excel('', $_GET['fileName'], $data);
}
?>
```

export_patrimonio_mysql_excel.php

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<?php
class Export{
    public function excel($name, $fileName, $data){
        // nome do arquivo
        $fileName = $fileName . '.xls';
        // Abrindo tag tabela e criando título da tabela
        $html = '';
        $html .= '<table border="0">';
        $html .= '<tr>';
  $html .= '<tr>';
  $html .= '<tr>';
  $html .= '<tr>';
  $html .= '<tr>';
  $html .= '<tr>';
  $html .= '<tr>';
        //$html .= '<th colspan="' . count($data) . '">' . $name . '</th>';
        $html .= '</tr>';
        $html .= '<tr>';
        // AQUI inicio COLOCAS EL TITULO DEL EXCEL SI LO NECESITAS//
  
  //foreach ($data[0] as $k => $v){
         //   $html .= '<th>' . ucfirst($k) . '</th>';
       // }
    
    // AQUI fin COLOCAS EL TITULO DEL EXCEL SI LO NECESITAS//
        $html .= '</tr>';
        // criando o conteúdo da tabela
        for($i=1; $i <= count($data); $i++){
            $html .= '<tr>';
            foreach ($data[$i] as $k => $v){
                $html .= '<td>' . $v . '</td>';
            }
            $html .= '</tr>';
        }
        $html .= '</table>';

        // configurando header para download
        header("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data");
        header("Content-Type: application/x-msexcel");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$fileName}\"");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        // envio conteúdo
        echo $html;
        exit;
    }

    public function xml($data){

    }
}
```

El campo `codigo_op` contiene números con ceros a la izquierda y necesito mantenerlos cuando exporte el excel aparezcan los ceros a la izquierda, tal como lo indico en el ejemplo. `000018`

Comment: ¿Qué usas para exportar a excel? Indica que es un campo de texto y se mantendrán.

Comment: he agregado export_patrimonio_mysql_excel.php para indicar que exporto, donde puedo indicar antes de crear el excel que es un campo texto? y cual seria el codigo?

Comment: No estás generando un excel, estás generando una tabla HTML que será abierto por Excel (ahí está el truco, por tener extensión `.xls`), por lo que no puedes indicar el tipo de contenido que tendrá la celda. En su lugar deberías usar una función de exportación de verdad como [`PHPExcel`](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/01-Getting-Started.md).

Answer (score 1):

**prueba poniendo esto:**

```
$style='mso-number-format:"@";'

foreach ($data[$i] as $k => $v){
    $html .= "<td style='".$style."'>" . $v . "</td>";
}
```

Comment: Sería conveniente que explicaras por qué lo que propones soluciona el problema del autor de la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Agrega un apostrofe en los valores para que excel reconozca los ceros

```
 foreach ($data[$i] as $k => $v){
     //cambia a comillas y poner apostrofe delante del valor
     $html .= "<td>'" . $v . "</td>";
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

les comento que busque por todos lados esta parte como generar un excel y conservar los ceros a la izquierda, y me encontre esta joya donde te indica como darle el formato a cada celda desde php https://www.cristalab.com/tutoriales/exportar-de-php-a-excel-y-dar-formato-a-celdas-c91335l/, esto si o si te funciona, saludos

Comment: Aunque teoricamente este enlace conteste la pregunta, es preferible que incluyas las partes esenciales del mismo en la respuesta. Los enlaces pueden caducar y desaparecer. Ademas llevar al usuario a que lea en otro lugar la respuesta, no es la mejor opción.