# ¿Exportar datos a excel con php?

Tags: php, html

Tengo el siguiente problema los archivos excel que genero no contienen información cuando desde html le envío un rango de fechas de un mes, si acorto los periodos el archivo excel si contiene información mi código es el siguiente de alguna manera me sirve por que la consultas que me traen menos registros si las puedo exportar pero cuando incrementan los registros el archivo excel me viene vacío.

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; name='excel'");

header("Content-Disposition: filename=ficheroExcel.xls");

header("Pragma: no-cache");

header("Expires: 0");

echo utf8_decode($_POST['datos_a_excel']);
```

Comment: Agrega tu código completo de PHP y da mas detalle de tu problema o si te muestra algún error, edita tu pregunta las veces que sean necesarias y dales el formato correspondiente. Revisa [tour] y [ask] de paso gana tus primeras medallas.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Exportar a excel desde mysql con php y mantener ceros a la izquierda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/98815/exportar-a-excel-desde-mysql-con-php-y-mantener-ceros-a-la-izquierda)